# Is there a cmake parser/lexer (in bison/flex) available somewhere?

Tags: cmake, bison

I need to parse CMakeLists.txt files for a small code editor project I am working on. I am therefore searching for a parser/lexer for the CMake language but can't seem to find anything using Google. Has anyone written such a grammar in bison with the corresponding lexer in flex? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can steal it from the [CMake source itself](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/e80e8eb609cc7dd8c4dca46b9c2819afd2293229/Source/LexerParser/cmListFileLexer.in.l).

Using lexer generated from that file could make you depend on internal CMake library called cmSys/kwSys. [Here is](https://cgit.kde.org/kdevelop.git/commit/?h=3477bb7783b6ee4ed66d0c2bf0e85de4ea9bd561) how we at KDevelop solved this.

Comment: thanks a lot for the pointer. So you used the lexer to return the various CMake language tokens but you still hand-coded your own parser? Correct? Also another point I am not sure about: how does a sequence such as add_library(mylib shared src/source1.cpp source2.cpp ...) is recognized by this lexer? I don't see any references in the lexer to keywords/commands such as add_library. thanks!

Comment: That's right, we have our own parser. I don't know exact rationale for this. As for your question - try feeding `add_library(mylib shared src/source1.cpp source2.cpp ...)` line to this lexer and then look what token did it generate.

Comment: @arrowd Your link stopped working.  Would you please provide an updated link to the commitdiff?

Comment: Sorry about that! I saw the link was broken, started wondering around the cmake repo and messed up the link to copy.

Comment: This is the new link https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/commit/3477bb7783b6ee4ed66d0c2bf0e85de4ea9bd561